# What is this random light in my engine bay near my front passenger wheel well?

Tags: honda, civic, lights, part-identification

I was replacing my headlights on my 2008 Honda Civic EX coupe and found this light bulb (I think?) plugged into a wire in my engine bay between the wheel well liner and my right headlight. It seems to have the same tabs as the housing for my low beams, but the bulbs look nothing alike. My high beams, fog lights, and turn signals all have bulbs installed. What is this?

[image: A mystery part!]

Comment: Where do the wires let it reach to?  Does it look like it should be at the headlight?

Comment: Was the light mounted to anything or just hanging there? When you turn on your headlights, highs or lows, fog lamps, turn signals, etc. does it light up?

Answer (score 1):

It sure looks like a FOG LAMP that has been removed from its housing.

If this car has fog lamps, see if the one nearest this is missing its bulb.  It may also be a side marker lamp or other lamp that has been pulled out and neglected to be replaced.

Look in the area for a lamp holder that is missing its lamp.